# Export And Import of Subsites Using PowerShell Script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, powershell, sharepoint-online

I am using SharePoint 2013.

The problem is as follows:

1. There are two Site Collections in a single Web Application. With the following Paths:
   /sites/Site1/Subsite1/ & /sites/Site2/Subsite2
2. Using Export-SPWeb `"http://SiteCollection/sites/Site1/Subsite1" -Path "C:\Export.cmp"`
   I have Exported the Subsite1.
3. Using Import-SPWeb `"http://SiteCollection/sites/Site1/Subsite2" -Path "C:\Export.cmp"`
   I have Imported the Subsite1 to Subsite2.

Everything is working perfect. The Subsite, the List, the Content Types, the columns all are getting imported. But except one, the Workflow instances that are created in Subsite1 are not getting imported in Subsite2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of import/export, Microsoft is clear in mentioning that workflow preservation may not occur. If you export a site or list from either the command line (“STSADM -o export” or the Export-SPWeb PowerShell cmdlet) or SharePoint 2010′s new Central Administration “Export a site or list” capability, you’ll likely lose workflow data and state.

Refer to 2013 Technet Documentation:- 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663490.aspx
[image]