# How to import a Website into SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have the following Problem: I want to build a SharePoint based Intranet for a company, so how can I import the Sites, Workflows etc, that I build in my "IDE" into the Company's SharePoint installation? I can not work on the live System i need to test before publishing.

Comment: do you want to move the whole site collection from IDE to Live farm or few Subsites?

Comment: In example I want to move just one Website

Comment: if you move whole site then backup and restore will copy the workflows but if you want wubsite then import & export will not move the workflows. how you created your workflows?

Comment: I use SharepointDesigner 2013 what do u mean with 
if you move whole site then backup and restore?

Comment: I mean backup-spsite & restore-Spsite(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901(v=office.15).aspx ). this will move a site collection

Answer (score 1):

First export the site with `Export-SPWeb` cmdlet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895(v=office.15).aspx.

You can then use `Import-SPWeb` cmdlet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613(v=office.15).aspx.

Comment: Thx, does this also Copy the Workflows on a list?

Comment: AFAIK it copies the entire site. It doesn't include custom WSPs, you have to deploy these manually, but from your post I think you don't have these.

Comment: I dont know what u mean with WSP. And i dont have these but i need to Export/Import a Site with Workflows

Comment: According to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74783/export-and-import-of-subsites-using-powershell-script, workflows are not exported, but I would give it a try because workflows 2013 are declarative now, i.e. they do not include custom code.